# How to fix "undefined method `empty?' for #<ContactInformation:0x007fc8be45cc98>: error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, associations

I had `has_many association` between a `user` and `contact_information`. I added two columns to `contact_information` as `address_one` and `address_two`.  And then changed the association to `has_one` association between the user and contact_information. But I am getting the error as:
`undefined method`empty?' for #`

In  app/models/concerns/user_associations.rb:

```
    has_many :contact_informations,
     -> { where(address_one: nil, address_two: nil) },
      as: :user
```

was changed to

```
    has_one :contact_information,
     -> { where(address_one: nil, address_two: nil) },
      as: :user
```

Then in `ContactInformationsController`, changed the `contact_informations` to `contact_information`. I am getting error in the `ContactInformationsController#show` as:

```
  def show
    if @user.contact_information.empty?
      redirect_to new_contact_information_path
    else
      redirect_to edit_contact_information_path
    end
  end
```

The `@user.contact_informations.empty?` was changed to `@user.contact_information.empty?`. But when I try to access the page,

`NoMethodError - undefined method`empty?' for #`

I looked up on INTERNET for similar issues and most of them said to convert it `.to_s`. But it did not solve my problem

The object of `contact_information` is present. Then why it is giving error on `.empty?`? Can please anybody explain this?

Thanks

Comment: make sure to restart server and db.indexing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`empty?` method is defined on enumerables, including active record relation, but it's not defined on single `ActiveRecord` objects, like `ContactInformation` instance. If you want to check the association presence, you can simply do:

```
if @user.contact_information
  redirect_to edit_contact_information_path
else
  redirect_to new_contact_information_path
end
```